# Wordpress truncating titles

Tags: php, wordpress, title, truncate

I have this working... but.

```
<?php
$thetitle = $post->post_title; /* or you can use get_the_title() */
$getlength = mb_strlen($thetitle);
$thelength = 25;
echo mb_substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";
?>
```

Just say the title is "Hey, how are you" and it truncates it after "Hey, ".

There is a space I want to eliminate after the comma and before the end quote.

Is there a way to do this? Otherwise the title looks like:

Hey, ...

Instead of:

Hey,...

Thanks

Comment: could you please provide one more example for explaining your problem

Comment: I want to truncate text, but if it's at a point where it's truncating it to the space, I want to remove that space. Example:

"example is great "

"example is great"

"hello "

"hello"

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo trim(mb_substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength));
```

you just need to trim the white spaces.